# Concatenate 2 row in to one row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, concatenation

i have two rows of data, I want to combine them like

[image]

> 147000.0000000 , 49000.00000

Previously I tried to concatenate two columns that resulted like this,[image]

how can I combine two rows in to one row?

Comment: you can use `FOR XML` for string concatenation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `FOR XML PATH` like this

**Query**

```
;WITH Table1 as 
(
SELECT 147000.0000000 as TDS_INAMOUNT
UNION ALL SELECT 49000.00000
)
SELECT 
STUFF((SELECT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),TDS_INAMOUNT)
FROM Table1
FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
).value('.','VARCHAR(2000)'),1,1,'')
```

**Output**

```
147000.0000000 , 49000.00000
```

If you want the output like

```
147000.0000000 in ASKARI HIGH YIELD SCHEME,49000.0000000 in ASKARI EQUITY FUND
```

Use this.

```
SELECT 
STUFF((SELECT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),TDS_INAMOUNT) + ' in ' + PRD_Name
FROM Table1
FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
).value('.','VARCHAR(2000)'),1,1,'')
```